# ASP.NET Razor Pages ATM Credit Card funds check

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I recently started learning Asp.Net with Razor Pages and I'm working on this project where users can enter his name last name and pin code for his credit card and if  inputs are in the database, it redirects him to user page and shows him how much money he has on his card.

But my validation is wrong, even when input is not in the database or is different from values in the database it redirects me to User page.Can someone help me to make my validation right.
Thanks in advance.
Here is all my code:
Index page:

```html
@page
@model BanlAcc.Pages.BankAcc.IndexModel

<br />

<h2 class="text-info">Enter your data</h2>


<div class=" border container" style="padding: 30px;">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Account.Name"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="Account.Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Account.Name"></span>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Account.Surname"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="Account.Surname" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Account.Surname"></span>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Account.Pin"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="Account.Pin" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Account.Pin"></span>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type="submit" value="Check" class="btn btn-primary form-control" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>

</div>

@section Scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BanlAcc.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BanlAcc.Pages.BankAcc
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private object _userRepository;

        public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Account Account { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("User");
                
            }
            else
            {
                return Page();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Account.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BanlAcc.Model
{
    public class Account
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(20)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(20)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Pin { get; set; }

        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

User page:

```html
@page
@model BanlAcc.Pages.BankAcc.AccountModel
<br />

<h2 class="text-info">Wellcome</h2>
```

Comment: _ModelState.IsValid_ doesn't validate your input against the database. It just checks if the model passed to the Post action is valid against the DataAnnotations attributes that your have set.

Comment: `Model state represents errors that come from two subsystems: model binding and model validation. `You can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0).In your code,it will check the rules in Account,such as `required,MaxLength`.